# Why the 4-acceleration in MCRF is not $(0,0,0,0)$?

Tags: physics, general-relativity, special-relativity

As you all know, the 4-velocity vector components in the momentarily comoving reference frame (MCRF) is given by  $$\vec U=(1,0,0,0)\ .$$ On the other hand, the 4-acceleration vector is given by $$\vec A=\cfrac{d\vec U}{d\tau}\ ,$$so the components of $\vec A$ in MCRF should be equal to $(0,0,0,0)$. But the textbook said $$\vec A = (0,a^1,a^2,a^3)\ .$$I know the components are given in that way is because of the orthogonality of $\vec U$ and $\vec A$, but i don’t know why it is not $(0,0,0,0)$.

By mathematics, it should be $(0,0,0,0)$, so what is wrong about the mathematics?

Comment: As you can see, punctuation gets misplaced when you put it after the double dollar signs for a displayed equation. You can include it within the equation, ideally set off by a `\;` space so that one doesn't read it as part of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong is, as usual, not mathematics but your understanding of it. The key word here is “momentarily”. The $4$-velocity takes the form $(1,0,0,0)$ at one particular time with respect to one particular inertial frame chosen for that purpose. Unless the body is moving with uniform velocity, the $4$-velocity will no longer take the form $(1,0,0,0)$ in that frame at other times – though it will again be possible to choose a *different* inertial frame in which it will again take that form. Thus, there is not *one*  momentarily comoving reference frame, but a different one for each instance, and the fact that the $4$-velocity takes the same form when expressed in these frames at these times does not prevent the $4$-velocity from changing over time and thus having a non-zero derivative.

Comment: But in MCRF, $$\vec x=(\tau,0,0,0)\ .$$Applying$$\vec U=\cfrac{d\vec x}{d\tau}\ ,$$we have $$\vec U=(1,0,0,0)\ .$$ So you see it is simply just differentiate the $\tau$ inside the $\vec x$, even in MCRF. So why not in calculating acceleration? What is the difference in calculating velocity and acceleration?

Comment: Maybe i get it, in MCRF, there is no $$\vec x=(\tau,0,0,0)\ ,$$it only has$$d\vec x=(d\tau,0,0,0)\ .$$The$\frac{d\vec x}{d\tau}$ is just applying division, not differentiation. Am i correct?

Comment: @KongyiuchongKong: No, that's not correct. $\frac{\mathrm d\vec x}{\mathrm d\tau}$ is indeed a derivative. The fact that $\frac{\mathrm d\vec x}{\mathrm d\tau}=(1,0,0,0)$ at one particular instant does not allow you to assume this for all instances and conclude that $\frac{\mathrm d^2\vec x}{\mathrm d\tau^2}=(0,0,0,0)$.

Comment: We can apply differentiation on $\vec x$, why not on $\vec U$? Why not also say $\vec A=(0,0,0,0)$ at one particular instant?

Comment: @KongyiuchongKong: No one said that you can't apply differentiation to $\vec U$. What you can't do is to arrange for the equation $\vec U=(1,0,0,0)$ to hold in a particular instant by choosing a particular inertial frame and then pretend that this equation holds at all times and can be differentiated. You can differentiate $\vec U$, but then you need to differentiate the actual funtion $\vec U(\tau)$, not some equation that only holds at one instant. There is no inertial frame in which $\vec U(\tau)=(1,0,0,0)$ for all $\tau$ (unless the motion is with uniform velocity, i.e. zero acceleration).

Comment: Oh i see, because at that particular instant, MCRF see that velocity of the particle is a constant, so it’s derivatives must be zero. A i correct?

Comment: @KongyiuchongKong: I don't understand that. It sounds wrong, but maybe I just don't understand it. Anyway, this discussion is getting too long for the comments. If you have further questions, you might want to ask a new question.